# Ember - Error while processing route: task.edit Assertion Failed: You may not pass `undefined` as id to the store's find method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I am developing application in Ember.js and RoR (Rails `4.0.3` and Ruby `2.0`).

Ember version:

```
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.12.1                 ember.js?body=1:4875 
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.19.2        ember.js?body=1:4875 
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.1                 ember.js?body=1:4875
```

`handlebars v3.0.3`

I used this tutorial

http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2015/04/18/arraycomputed-refactor/

to implement some custom components, but there is no need to show them, they are irrevelant to main problem.

---

When I want to to go from `ListsRoute` to `TaskEditRoute` it throws me an error

```
Error while processing route: task.edit Assertion Failed: 
  You may not pass `undefined` as id to the store's find method
  Error: Assertion Failed: You may not pass `undefined` as id to the store's find method
```

-router.js

```
EmTasks.Router.map(function(){
  this.route("lists", {
    path: '/'
  });

  this.route('profile', {
    path: '/profile'
  });

  this.resource("task", {path: "/task/:task_id"}, function () {
      this.route('edit', {path: "edit"});
  });
});
```

-lists_route.js

```
EmTasks.ListsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('list');
  },

  actions: {
      addList: function(param) {
          this.store.createRecord('list', {
              name: $("#list_name").val()
          }).save();
          $("#list_name").val('');
      }
  }
});
```

-task_edit_route.js

```
EmTasks.TaskEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        var url = this.get('router.url');
        var id = url.split("/")[2]

        console.log("TaskEditRoute params:", params);

        return this.store.find("task", id);
    }
});
```

-lists.handlebars

```
<div class="row">
  {{#each model as |list|}}
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{x-list list=list}}     <!-- custom component - working -->

        {{x-add-task list=list}} <!-- custom component - working -->

        {{#each list.tasks as |task|}}

            {{#link-to 'task.edit' task}}
                {{task.name}}
            {{/link-to}}

            <a href='#/task/{{task.id}}/edit'>
                {{task.name}}
            </a>

            {{x-task task=task}} <!-- custom component - working -->
        {{/each}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

---

So when I click on the link generated by `link-to`,

```
{{#link-to 'task.edit' task}}
  {{task.name}}
{{/link-to}}
```

it doesn't redirect me to new URL and when I check params using console.log I can see they are empty.

```
 TaskEditRoute: params Object {}
```

Moreover I get this error:

```
Error while processing route: task.edit Assertion Failed: You may not pass `undefined` as id to the store's find method Error: Assertion Failed: You may not pass `undefined` as id to the store's find method
```

When I click on the custom, hand-written link

```
 <a href='#/task/{{task.id}}/edit'>
   {{task.name}}
 </a>
```

I am redirected, but still the `params` in TaskEditRoute are empty.

But I can then get current url (either `window.location.href` OR ember way `this.get('router.url')`), parse it and fetch ID.

So it works... but it is tricky, hacky.

**Why... the standard way of doing things, described [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/defining-your-routes/) doesnt works?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the dynamic segment `id` defined on the `task` route, not the `task.edit` route.

```
EmTasks.TaskRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        console.log("TaskEditRoute params:", params);

        return this.store.find("task", params.id);
    }
});
```

As of Ember 1.4 or something child routes will automatically use their parent's model unless the child route chooses to use something different in its own model hook.  So you should have the parents model without having to do anything in the `TaskEditRoute`